# How to add random generated numbers to a row

Tags: r

I am trying to generate 6 random numbers to my table without having to specify each point. I wrote out random numbers for "Heather" and "Laurel", but I want another way of accomplishing.

```
student_names = c("Henry", "Cat", "Shelby", "Eren", "Eva", "Carter", "Dustin")
n_students <- length(student_names)

grades <- tibble(
  name = student_names,
  HW1 = rnorm(n_students, mean = 80, sd = 2) %>% round(0),
  HW2 = rnorm(n_students, mean = 80, sd = 5) %>% round(0),
  HW3 = rnorm(n_students, mean = 90, sd = 8) %>% round(0),
  HW4 = rnorm(n_students, mean = 60, sd = 10) %>% round(0),
  HW5 = rnorm(n_students, mean = 80, sd = 10) %>% round(0),
  HW6 = rnorm(n_students, mean = 90, sd = 5) %>% round(0)
)

grades <- rbind(grades, list("Heather", 100, 100, 100, 92, 95, 99))
grades <- rbind(grades, list("Laurel", 100, 100, 100, 100, 99, 105))
```

Comment: Write a function whose arguments are (1) the existing `grades` tibble, (2) the student name and (3) optionally the mean & sd for `rnorm()` and then inside the function create the new row, `rbind` it to `grades` and then return the modified `grades`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can call the function in a loop outputing a data.frame column for every iteration (`map2_dfc`), then `bind_cols` with the names column.
Since the arguments to `rnorm` are all constants except `sd`, we loop through a vector of `sd`s, and `1:6`, the last one just for the number of repetitions.

```
set.seed(1)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map2_dfc(1:6,
        c(2, 5, 8, 10, 10, 10),
        ~rnorm(n_students, mean = 90, sd = .y)) %>% 
    rename_with(~glue("HW{1:6}")) %>% 
    bind_cols(names=student_names, .)

# A tibble: 7 × 7
  names    HW1   HW2   HW3   HW4   HW5   HW6
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Henry   88.7  93.7  99.0  97.8  85.2  85.9
2 Cat     90.4  92.9  89.6  90.7  94.2  86.1
3 Shelby  88.3  88.5  89.9  70.1 104.   89.4
4 Eren    93.2  97.6  97.6  96.2  89.0 101. 
5 Eva     90.7  91.9  96.6  89.4  93.9  97.6
6 Carter  88.4  86.9  94.8  88.4  89.5  88.4
7 Dustin  91.0  78.9  97.4  75.3  76.2  87.5
```